# How can I print each character in my character array using pointers?

Tags: c

I wrote the following code:

```
char arrayD[] = "asdf";
char *arraypointer = &arrayD;
while(*arraypointer != '\0'){
    printf("%s \n", arraypointer+1);
    arraypointer++;
}
```

I tried %d %c to print each character. However, with %c I get "? ? ? ?", with %s I get "sdf sd f ". etc. What am I missing here?

Comment: Please add a full example, see [mcve]. Also, what output did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're printing pointer addresses, instead of what the pointer is pointing to. Also arrayD is the address, you don't need &arrayD. Here is a complete working sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char arrayD[] = "asdf";
    char *arraypointer = arrayD;
    while(*arraypointer != '\0'){
        printf("%c \n", *(arraypointer+1));
        arraypointer++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did OP need the `+1`?

Comment: I don't know. Probably not but I kept his logic in place and only checked his problem: that he was printing '?' with %c.

Comment: I am confused on the `printf` statement, where we see `arrayPointer+1`, doesn't this miss character on first index and point out of bound? I haven't tested it though.

Comment: @LuzanBaral forget about +1. it is an error. You will try to print the 0x00 as well and you will miss the first char

Comment: @P__J__ Is `printf("%c", '\0')` legit though?

Comment: @Spikatrix did I wrote that?

Comment: @P__J__ I'm just asking that. Does it invoke Undefined Behavior or something or is it legit?

Comment: No, why? -------

Comment: @Spikatrix it is not "undefined behaviour" as far as the C standard goes, but what actually appears on the terminal (if anything) depends on the environment.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ah, yes. That's exactly what I was asking clarification on. Thanks.

Comment: @CristianBidea Thanks man, that cleared up a lot of confusion? I wasn't dereferencing the pointer. And understood the extra '&' for arrayD as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
void print_string_by_chars(const char *str)
{
    while(*str)
    {
        putc(*str++, stdout);
        putc('\n', stdout);
    }
}
```

---

usage in your case:

```
print_string_by_chars(arrayD)
```

Comment: Thanks, Another substitute for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

hey you were not dereferncing the pointer. you did
`arrayptr` but you need to do `*arrayptr`. Also you need to use %c if you are printing single character.

here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char arrayD[] = "asdf";
    char *arraypointer = arrayD;
    while(*arraypointer != '\0'){
        printf("%c \n", *(arraypointer));
        arraypointer++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

output :

```
a 
s 
d 
f
```

Comment: Thanks, this a complete solution as well.